Open a list with email clients programatically on Android
I am trying to open a list of email clients in order to send an email.
So far, I have the following code:
    val fileLocation = File(getExternalFilesDir(null).toString())
    val fullPath: String? = "${fileLocation.path}/${jsonFileName}"
    val fileToSend = File(fullPath)

    val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        context!!,
        context!!.applicationContext.packageName + ".provider",
        fileToSend
    )

    val mailText: String = ""

    val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    emailIntent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:")
    emailIntent.type = "text/plain"

    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, qlikAppName)
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mailText)

    try
    {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Choose Email Client..."))
    }
    catch (e: Exception)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

This works just fine except for the fact it opens a list of apps to share with. Unfortunately, those apps include more than just the email client.
Using Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO) opens the default mail client but it does no attach the file.
Any ideas?

sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
